# FindMeetingTimes only returning 5 suggestions (free time slots) when more is available. Is this a known bug?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using this endpoint below to retrieve upcoming free times for a room and it appears the results cap at 5 MeetingTimeSlot.  Is this a known issue that being work?  Is anyone else experiencing similar behavior? Is there a flag for pagination(is this is a pagination issue)?

Endpoint: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/findmeetingtimes

Request body:

```
{ 
  "Attendees": [ 
    { 
      "Type": "Required",  
      "EmailAddress": { 
        "Name": "Fanny",
        "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com" 
      } 
    } 
  ],  
  "LocationConstraint": { 
    "IsRequired": "false",  
    "SuggestLocation": "true",  
    "Locations": [ 

    ] 
  },  
  "TimeConstraint": { 
    "ActivityDomain":"Work",
    "Timeslots": [ 
      { 
        "Start": { 
          "DateTime": "2018-09-25T07:00:00",  
          "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
        },  
        "End": { 
          "DateTime": "2018-09-25T17:00:00",  
          "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time" 
        } 
      } 
    ] 
  },  
  "ReturnSuggestionReasons": "true"

}
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Microsoft.OutlookServices.MeetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "EmptySuggestionsReason": "",
    "MeetingTimeSuggestions": [
        {
            "Confidence": 100,
            "OrganizerAvailability": "Free",
            "SuggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "MeetingTimeSlot": {
                "Start": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T08:00:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                "End": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T08:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "AttendeeAvailability": [
                {
                    "Availability": "Free",
                    "Attendee": {
                        "Type": "Required",
                        "EmailAddress": {
                            "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "DisplayName": "PDXXMOBILESH",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 4",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXIC Studio 3",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 2",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXic Enclave",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Confidence": 100,
            "OrganizerAvailability": "Free",
            "SuggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "MeetingTimeSlot": {
                "Start": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T09:00:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                "End": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T09:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "AttendeeAvailability": [
                {
                    "Availability": "Free",
                    "Attendee": {
                        "Type": "Required",
                        "EmailAddress": {
                            "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "DisplayName": "PDXXMOBILESH",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 4",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXIC Studio 3",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 2",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXic Enclave",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Confidence": 100,
            "OrganizerAvailability": "Free",
            "SuggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "MeetingTimeSlot": {
                "Start": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T09:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                "End": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T10:00:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "AttendeeAvailability": [
                {
                    "Availability": "Free",
                    "Attendee": {
                        "Type": "Required",
                        "EmailAddress": {
                            "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "DisplayName": "PDXXMOBILESH",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 4",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXIC Studio 3",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 2",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXic Enclave",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Confidence": 100,
            "OrganizerAvailability": "Free",
            "SuggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "MeetingTimeSlot": {
                "Start": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T10:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                "End": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T11:00:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "AttendeeAvailability": [
                {
                    "Availability": "Free",
                    "Attendee": {
                        "Type": "Required",
                        "EmailAddress": {
                            "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "DisplayName": "PDXXMOBILESH",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 4",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXIC Studio 3",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 2",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXic Enclave",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Confidence": 100,
            "OrganizerAvailability": "Free",
            "SuggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "MeetingTimeSlot": {
                "Start": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T16:30:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                "End": {
                    "DateTime": "2018-09-25T17:00:00.0000000",
                    "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "AttendeeAvailability": [
                {
                    "Availability": "Free",
                    "Attendee": {
                        "Type": "Required",
                        "EmailAddress": {
                            "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Locations": [
                {
                    "DisplayName": "PDXXMOBILESH",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxxmobilesh@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 4",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "pdxicstudio4@rogueinc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },[enter image description here][1]
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXIC Studio 3",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Telepres, Portland IC Studio 2",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWTPSTUDIO2@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown",
                    "Address": {
                        "Type": "Home",
                        "Street": "",
                        "City": "",
                        "State": "",
                        "CountryOrRegion": "",
                        "PostalCode": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName": "Conf, PDXic Enclave",
                    "LocationEmailAddress": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "LocationType": "ConferenceRoom",
                    "UniqueId": "PDXICRWENCLAVE@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "UniqueIdType": "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The calendar for the room and myself look like this:

Thanks,
Jenny

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue.  By default, if the "MaxCandidates" property is not provided or set, it will return 5 suggestions.

Once I set it to 99, all available time slot returned properly.